# Comment connaitre le registre d'un mot ?

Tags: usage, ressources, registre

Comment peut-on connaître le registre d'un mot ? Par exemple, comment sait-on si on peut employer un mot comme « éloquent » dans un contexte plus relâché ?

Comment: Ha bhé alors... bhein! Comme dans toutes les langues. En plus, on **peut** toujours utiliser un mot du registre dit soutenu dans un registre qui l'est moins. L'inverse, ce n'est même pas qu'on ne **peut** pas, c'est juste que des fois... y **vaut mieux** pas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tout d'abord, les dictionnaires indiquent si les mots font partie du registre "familier" ou pas. Cela indique les mots qui ne s'utilisent pas dans un registre formel, mais l'inverse n'est pas vrai.

Dans l'autre sens, il n'y a en effet pas de règle stricte. Une première vérification consisterait à regarder s'il n'existe pas un synonyme dans le registre familier. Ensuite, je dirais que le niveau de pédanterie peut s'évaluer à la fréquence d'utilisation de chaque synonyme. A priori, les synonymes les plus fréquents dans un ngram sont à favoriser dans un contexte relâché. Cette règle n'est toutefois pas absolue car les ngram se basent sur des textes écrits, donc certains termes plus spécifiques à la langue orale pourraient y être défavorisés.

Comme exemple, plusieurs synonymes d'éloquent (le choix des synonymes doit bien entendu s'adapter au contexte, dont je ne dispose pas ici). L'usage d'éloquent y semble assez courant, contrairement à "disert", par exemple.

[image]